# Anonymous listings environment

Tags: listings, environments, counters, environment-variables

I would like to be able to switch off the listings counter individually with asterisk (*), like one would suppress an equation number using

```
\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}
```

As with the equation environment, the asterisk should not increment the listings counter, i.e.

```
\begin{lstlisting}This will become Listing 1\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting*}This one is anonymous\end{lstlisting*}
\begin{lstlisting}This is Listing 2\end{lstlisting}
```

How does one do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `label=...` without `caption` does not increase the `lstlisting` counter!

Either don't use any `caption` in relevant `lstlisting` call or define a new `lstlisting*` environment with `\lstnewenvironment` to make the environment more outstanding in the source code to be unnumbered, but it is not safe about the `caption=...` option anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

% This is not needed actually.     
\lstnewenvironment{lstlisting*}[1][]{%
 \lstset{#1}%
}{}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\section{Foo stuff}
\thelstlisting
\begin{lstlisting}[label={lst:first-one}] % Will increment the listings counter
Foo
\end{lstlisting}

\autoref{lst:first-one} % This prints 'Listing 2' since the counter is taken from the 2nd section (Foo Stuff), not from the first lstlisting environment. The output of `\thelstlisting` is still 0!

\begin{lstlisting*}[language={C}]
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
\end{lstlisting*}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Foo caption},label={lst:second-one}] % Will increment the listings counter
Foo
\end{lstlisting}

\thelstlisting

\autoref{lst:second-one}

\ref{lst:second-one}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The easiest way is to use the `title=` option